# Big list question on writing mail with emacs

Tags: discussion

This question came to me after reading this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3629/184) and its comments.

EDIT: The question is now [posted](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12927/184).

In my opinion, setting emacs up to read and/or write mail is *hard*. And given how many packages exist to achieve this, it shouldn't be that hard. I have stopped counting how many people (including myself, mental voice version) told me "Mail with emacs? Oh, yes, I tried this and that, and this happened, then I gave up". I know many emacs fanatics, only one of them reads his mail with emacs. He writes them with something else.

Yet it is also something that a lot of people want to do at some point.

There is an overview on mail packages on the emacs wiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryMail
This surely is a very nice and encouraging entry point for beginners ("sarcasm")!

In my opinion, the emacs.sx website is one of the best place that the internet can offer to have a list of mail solution for emacs which would be:

- nicely formatted (no need to dive through three layers of pages to read the essentials about a package)
- nicely sorted (votes should give an overview of popularity, and implicitely usability, of a package)
- curated (obsolete packages would be marked as such, etc)

This list would contain a very basic community-wiki question (as broad as possible, to be available as a duplicate candidate for as many questions as possible on that topic), and then one answer per package or solution.

As an example of how this can work without being a mess, you can see this [list of latex IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/9517), and the associated [meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3253/9517) which became necessary at some point. I don't think we'd need to go as far as tex.sx for that (no need to have nominated curators, for example), but should this list appear, it would be a good idea to agree beforehand on a template for answers, for example.

This template could include information such as external dependencies, supported protocols, authentication protocol, password storage method, support for offline work...

One last point: as I understand it, a lot of the difficulties come from the email protocols rather than emacs, and users underestimating the number of tools required to recieve or send a mail. Maybe an extra accepted answer (to be above the list) could be used to sum this up, and explain exactly where does emacs come into play. On the other hand, I believe that this explanation could be rather off-topic on this site, so it could probably be replaced by a link to another sx site about the question.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As long as we delineated very clearly here a model for the answers to follow, then yes I think it would be something very helpful. The question will need to specify it's looking for very thorough answers, so that we have a reason to discourage short answers. The problem is whether anyone will be willing to write these long answers.

Comment: I don't think short answers should be discouraged, as long as there are people willing to edit them into longer answer. Isn't that why community wiki is for, after all?

Comment: I hope this takes off. I'm a beginning user who has stumbled here and there with email on emacs. Presently I'm limping forward with Gnus, which I chose simply because it was the only thing I could get to work. But it is a little clunky for my actual needs at times. I'm very interested to read concise, up-to-date summaries of available approaches as well as checking the number of upvotes to see what's popular with whom.

Comment: Here is another big list question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13197/what-do-you-use-org-mode-for (and I created the [tag:big-list] tag there, feel free to use it on other similar questions).

Comment: ... although the tag was removed by a moderator, so I fell back to using a "big list -" prefix in the subject line, which seems to be the usage on tex.se

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know, I would be happy to give my answer on a how-to-use-emacs-for-mail question.  These days I use Mu4e for the mail I don't filter to oblivion in Gmail.  Mu4e is shipped along with with [mu](https://github.com/djcb/mu), which I use together with [offlineimap](http://offlineimap.org/).  Mu4e seems fairly well documented, but I can share the (generic) details of my configuration, which I used to read 2 different accounts and to send mail.  Ages ago, I used [Rmail](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rmail.html), with filters in procmail but I don't think I have the configs around anymore.

I could offer similar personal configurations for *Org*, *Evil*, *Eww*, and some other things.

If you Google "[dot emacs github](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dot+emacs+github)" you'll find lots of general purpose configs, which could also be interesting for research purposes.

Comment: The question is now online: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12927/184